# how to call multiple rest calls in a component did mount?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, web-parts, spfx

I am trying to get SP lists from web using the below code. but we also want to get list template using

```
public componentDidMount() {
      let reactcontexthandiler= this;
      jquery.ajax({
        url: `${GetSpLists.siteurl}/_api/web/lists?select=Title&$filter=Hidden eq false`,
        type:"GET",
         headers:{'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose;'},
         success : function (resultData){
          reactcontexthandiler.setState({sitecontents: resultData.d.results});
         },
         error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorthrown){
          }
        });
    }
```

```
/_api/web/ListTemplates/
```

Here we also want to get list template type, how can i add another rest call here in this same function ?
Or
please assist me how to call multiple rest calls in TSX file during the SPFX webpart

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Promise.all()?
Check for async api calls examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promise.all function to execute

```
componentDidMount() {
    Promise.all([fetch('url'), fetch('url2')])

      .then(([res1, res2]) => { 
         return Promise.all([res1.json(), res2.json()]) 
      })
      .then(([res1, res2]) => {
        // set state in here
      });
}
```

Comment: Hi @RaytheonXie-MSFT if you make me to understand with the above piece of code, that would be really helpful to me to understand, please update the code with above piece of code

Answer (score 0):

pls try promise all

```
const fetcher = (path) => fetch(path).then((res) => res.json())
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await Promise.all([fetcher('http://localhost:3000/posts'), fetcher('http://localhost:3000/comments')])
      console.log(res)
    } catch (error) {}
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])
```

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-curran-55zfg7?file=/src/App.js)